# CSS Stylesheets does't apply on IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I' am running into a issue, the site is still in my localhost. Where the css links are not including into into the page. It works in all other browser expect IE7 and IE8.

I' am using WordPress 3.6, Bootstrap 3, Modernizr and jQuery.

**Source Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie-7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie-8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie-9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"> 
        <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <title><?php echo title(); ?></title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/common.css"/>
      <?php if(is_front_page()){ ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/home.css"/><?php } ?>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/media.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS_PATH; ?>/print.css" media="print"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo JS_PATH; ?>/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">var template = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';</script>
    </head>
```

**Chrome Head**
[image]

**IE8 Head**
[image]

What I thought this might be something to do with DOCTYPE so I changed to HTML4 but still its not working. Also note that it works on IE8 Browser Mode and Document Mode as Quirks but doesn't work on Standard Mode

Comment: The `endif` for `if gt IE 8` is missing.

Comment: I see no closing for the last <!--[if gt IE 8]>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using conditional comments.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"> 
        <head>
```

You never end the concom for the `<html>` start tag for gt IE8. Everything before the next comment is hidden in browsers that match that.

Add `<!--<![endif]-->`.